# how to write an int to RFID tag and when read then store that in an array

Tags: arduino-nano

The writing code is from the MFRC522 Example below:

I have added an array to store the value but it does not store it as the same value written to it in the writing. instead it stores it as byte values.
I am fairly new so would appreciate any help.

```cpp
/*
 * Write personal data of a MIFARE RFID card using a RFID-RC522 reader
 * Uses MFRC522 - Library to use ARDUINO RFID MODULE KIT 13.56 MHZ WITH TAGS SPI W AND R BY COOQROBOT. 
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 *
 * Hardware required:
 * Arduino
 * PCD (Proximity Coupling Device): NXP MFRC522 Contactless Reader IC
 * PICC (Proximity Integrated Circuit Card): A card or tag using the ISO 14443A interface, eg Mifare or NTAG203.
 * The reader can be found on eBay for around 5 dollars. Search for "mf-rc522" on ebay.com. 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);        // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();               // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();        // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Write personal data on a MIFARE PICC "));
}

void loop() {

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }


  byte buffer[34];
  byte block;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;
  byte len;

  Serial.setTimeout(20000L) ;     // wait until 20 seconds for input from serial
  // Ask personal data: Family name
  Serial.println(F("Enter the weight, ending with#"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 30) ; // read family name from serial
  for (byte i = len; i < 30; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

  block = 1;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("PCD_Authenticate() success: "));

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

}
```

and the reading code is :

`````````````````````````````````````cpp
/*
 * Initial Author: ryand1011 (https://github.com/ryand1011)
 *
 * Reads data written by a program such as "rfid_write_personal_data.ino"
 *
 * See: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/tree/master/examples/rfid_write_personal_data
 *
 * Uses MIFARE RFID card using RFID-RC522 reader
 * Uses MFRC522 - Library
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

int weightArray[2];
int counter = 0;

//*****************************************************************************************//
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                           // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();                                                  // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();                                              // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Read personal data on a MIFARE PICC:"));    //shows in serial that it is ready to read

}

//*****************************************************************************************//
void loop() {

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  //some variables we need
  byte block;
  byte len;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;

  //-------------------------------------------

  // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Detected");

  byte buffer1[18];

  block = 4;
  len = 18;

  //------------------------------------------- GET FIRST NAME
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 4, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834 of MFRC522.cpp file
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer1, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  //PRINT FIRST NAME
/*  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    if (buffer1[i] != 32)
    {
      Serial.write(buffer1[i]);
    }
  }
  Serial.print(" ");
*/
  //---------------------------------------- GET LAST NAME

  byte buffer2[18];
  block = 1;

  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(mfrc522.uid)); //line 834
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Authentication failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer2, &len);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("Reading failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  //PRINT LAST NAME
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.write(buffer2[i]);  
    }


  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(weightArray) / sizeof(weightArray[1]); i++) {
    Serial.print(weightArray[i]);
  }

  counter++;

  Serial.println(F("\n**End Reading**\n"));

  delay(1000); //change value if you want to read cards faster

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}
//*****************************************************************************************//
````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````

Comment: OK, so you posted some code.  But in order for people to help you, please also include a question.

Answer (score 1):

First you are not writing `int` value during write as, buffer is defined as `byte` type. Your are just type casting it `char*` during serial read for storing data. And Your are writing just first 16 value in your CARD, so you might not get the expected results.

`byte` data type provides only `8 bit` or `1 byte` of memory location.
`int` data type provides `2 bytes` or `4 bytes` of memory location.